# Node.js lazy require module

Tags: node.js, module, lazy-loading, require

I'm writing a lazy module require() or import

```
const lazy = new Proxy({}, 
  {
    get: function (target, name) {
      console.log('lazy require', { target, name })
      return require(name)
    }
  }
)

/**
  * @param {string} Module Name
  * @example const expo = requirez('expo')
  */
export default function requirez(name) {
    return lazy[name]
}
```

and oddly when I run it I get:

> Cannot find module "."

The console.log statement logs:

> lazy require `{target: {…}, name: "./Linking"}`

So `require(name)` should be getting called as: `require("./Linking")`

Not as `require(".")` which the error is indicating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a related bug report:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4921

Since node `require` tree resolution is evaluated/analyzed statically and webpack assumes this it fails on dynamic resolution.

Also, on browser webpack will have to transpile the required bundle before running in the browser thus dynamic lazy requires can't be run after transpilation. You'd be missing the transpiled source of that required module.

I've tried using `import()` but it also has bugs:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4292#issuecomment-280165950